# "In" as a modal particle?

Tags: standard-german

Duden offers "zur Angabe der Art und Weise, in der etwas geschieht, vorhanden ist" as a definition of "in," with "modal; mit Dativ" as its grammar. What is meant by "modal" here? Does it function as a modal particle. If so, how?

Addendum: Could you please provide a definition of "modal"?

Answer (score 3):

The sentence you quoted defines what is meant with modal:

"zur Angabe der Art und Weise, in der etwas geschieht, vorhanden ist": for specifying the way in which something is happening or present.

It does not mean that "in" functions as a modal particle. It's still a preposition, but a modal one, not a local or temporal one.

Compare:

> Ich gehe ins Haus (local)
>
> Ich gehe in einer Stunde nach Hause. (temporal)
>
> Ich gehe in gemächlicher Art nach Hause. (modal)

Comment: Would you mind adding a definition for modal prepositions?

Comment: I already explained what modal means in this context, and what a preposition is should be clear.